# Website will not re-deploy after successful deployment, how can I fix it?

Tags: heroku

I'm trying to pass this classs. I need to deploy this website on heroku, and I did it yesterday and it worked fine, I tried it again today and now there's an error even though I didn't change anything in the code. It keeps failing once it tries to install node_modules
[deployment failure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yhpHJ.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: Heroku has a weird thing where it won't ever re-deploy the same commit. This has nothing to do with Git, except that because it won't re-deploy the *same* commit, you must make some sort of trivial change (even a change-nothing change) to try to get Heroku to re-deploy the same thing. But always read the `remote:` messages: they came *from* Heroku, and since Git is merely relaying the bad news, Git can't tell you anything that Heroku didn't say, so everything useful is in those `remote:` lines.